# How to collect liquids you can't safely stand in?

Tags: noita

How do I bottle things like acid, teleportatium, and lava?  I can't stand in them to put them in a bottle.  In the cases of acid and lava, I die, and in the cases of teleportatium and polymorphine, I teleport away or polymorph into something that can't use a bottle.

Is it even possible to put these things in bottles?

Answer (score 6):

Empty and throw the bottle into whatever it is you're trying to get. This very problem confused me for a while too till I realized you can throw and empty the flasks.

Comment: How do I pick it back up?  Surely there will be some liquid left outside the flask that will effect me.

Comment: if its shallow you can just hover at the top and hold loot to get it. However, if its deep you have to either drain it from below, change it by adding something else to it or maybe freeze/burn it out with stillness/fire.Also,try pooling the substance to a shallow spot before throwing the flask in and get it before the flask is completely submerged